# Use of structure member operator in C

Tags: c, c99, structure

I don't understand why my C program does not compile.

The error message is:

```
$ gcc token_buffer.c -o token_buffer
token_buffer.c:22: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘.’ token
```

The first structure – **token** is intended to be used in many places, so I use an optional structure tag. The second structure declaration I am not reusing anywhere else so I am not using a structure tag but instead I define a variable named **buffer**.

And then compilation fails when I try to assign a value to one of the members of this structure.

Help?

```
/*
 * token_buffer.c 
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

/* A token is a kind-value pair */
struct token {
    char *kind;
    double value;   
};

/* A buffer for a token stream */
struct {
    bool full;
    struct token t; 
} buffer;

buffer.full = false;

main()
{
    struct token t;
    t.kind = "PLUS";
    t.value = 0;

    printf("t.kind = %s, t.value = %.2f\n", t.kind, t.value);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot have free-standing operations in C: you need to put initialization into your `main`.

```
int main() { // Don't forget to make your main return int explicitly
    struct token t;
    buffer.full = false; // <---- Here it is legal

    t.kind = "PLUS";
    t.value = 0;

    printf("t.kind = %s, t.value = %.2f\n", t.kind, t.value);
    return 0; // main should return status to the operating system
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It makes sense now, I believe that I have confused 'assignment' and 'initialisation'.

Comment: @Gruffalo In C99, you can also use [designated initializers](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fdesignators.htm). If you add `buffer = {.full = false};` to the declaration of the `buffer`, it should work too.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted! The `token` member will be assigned later so I am not worried really, but I wanted to initialise `full`. Many thanks again!

Comment: Please don't call it initialization. This is an assignment.

Comment: @JensGustedt Right, what was intended as *initialization* became an *assignment* when it was moved into `main()`.

Answer (score 1):

The offending part is:     `buffer.full = false;`
as you set the value outside.

Put this statement inside `main()`.

Answer (score 0):

Assignement and initialization are two different things in C. Just do

```
struct {
    bool full;
    struct token t; 
} buffer = { .full = false };
```